# Speed up PowerShell Get-Counter and Get-Process

Tags: powershell, optimization

The following PowerShell code works, generates the output shown below, and is reproducible.

The general question is: how can I speed it up?

The biggest bottlenecks are the `Get-Process` and `Get-Counter` cmdlets.

**EDITED** based on @LotPings comments.

```proto
$LogicalProcessors = (Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor 
    -Property NumberOfLogicalProcessors).NumberOfLogicalProcessors;

function myTop([String]$SortCol='CPU', [Int32]$top=30) {
    $NameArray = get-counter '\Process(*)\ID Process' -EA SilentlyContinue | 
        Select -Expand CounterSamples | Select InstanceName
    $IdArray = get-counter '\Process(*)\ID Process' -EA SilentlyContinue | 
        Select -Expand CounterSamples | Select CookedValue
    $CpuArray = get-counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' -EA SilentlyContinue | 
        Select -Expand CounterSamples | Select CookedValue
    $MemArray = get-counter '\Process(*)\Working Set - Private' -EA SilentlyContinue | 
        Select -Expand CounterSamples | Select CookedValue

    $procTbl = get-process | select ID, Name, Description, MainWindowTitle

    $TopTable = @()
    For ($i=0; $i -lt $NameArray.Length; $i++) {
            $procIndex = [array]::indexof($procTbl.ID, [Int32]$IdArray[$i].CookedValue)
            if ($NameArray[$i].InstanceName -eq '_total') {continue}
            if ($NameArray[$i].InstanceName -eq 'memory compression') {continue}
            if ($NameArray[$i].InstanceName -eq 'idle') {
                $NewRow = [PSCustomObject]@{
                Name = $NameArray[$i].InstanceName;
                ID = $IdArray[$i].CookedValue;
                CPU = ($CpuArray[$i].CookedValue) / $LogicalProcessors;
                Mem = $MemArray[$i].CookedValue;
                procID = $procTbl.ID[$procIndex];
                Description = $procTbl.Description[$procIndex];
                Title = $procTbl.MainWindowTitle[$procIndex];
                }
            $TopTable += $NewRow
            } else {
                $NewRow = [PSCustomObject]@{
                Name = $NameArray[$i].InstanceName;
                ID = $IdArray[$i].CookedValue;
                CPU = $CpuArray[$i].CookedValue;
                Mem = $MemArray[$i].CookedValue;
                procID = $procTbl.ID[$procIndex];             
                Description = $procTbl.Description[$procIndex];
                Title = $procTbl.MainWindowTitle[$procIndex];
                }
            $TopTable += $NewRow
            }
        }

    $TopTable | sort -des $SortCol | select -f $top |`
    select Name, ID,`
        @{Name='CPU'; Expression = {("{0:N1}%" -f $_.CPU) } },`
        @{Name='Mem'; Expression = {("{0:N0} K" -f ($_.Mem /1kb) )} },
        Description, Title
}

While(1) {$p = myTop -SortCol CPU -top 12 | ft -a ; sleep 0; cls; $p}
```

Output (refresh rate approximately 2 seconds):

```
Name                  ID CPU   Mem          Description        Title
----                  -- ---   ---          -----------        -----
memory compression  2768 0.0%  996,516 kb
code                8828 0.0%  232,084 kb   Visual Studio Code
chrome             28620 0.0%  217,088 kb   Google Chrome
code               41596 0.0%  180,076 kb   Visual Studio Code
chrome             33772 0.0%  140,976 kb   Google Chrome      Speed up PowerShell Get-Counter and Get-Pro...
code               22600 0.0%  127,952 kb   Visual Studio Code
teams              27412 0.0%  105,656 kb   Microsoft Teams
powershell         55692 1.5%  95,596 kb    Windows PowerShell
mcshield            8596 0.0%  93,784 kb
onedrive           59644 0.0%  80,796 kb    Microsoft OneDrive
code               21708 0.0%  79,688 kb    Visual Studio Code
powershell         64228 0.0%  74,508 kb                       Administrator: Windows PowerShell
```

Comment: For a start: use `Get-Process` only once as you need to attach the property nevertheless, it makes no sense to use 4 different variables (and .Name isn't used at all). Merge $NameArray,$IdArray with same source. Don't use `| foreach {$_.CounterSamples} | select ` but `Select -Expand CounterSamples | Select InstanceName`

Comment: @LotPings - I made the changes you suggested:  Single call to `get-process | select ID, Name, Description, MainWindowTitle` then got each array from that table. Replaced  `| foreach {$_.CounterSamples} | select` with `| Select -Expand CounterSamples | Select`, but there has been no noticeable speed increase.

Comment: `Name` was just left over from checking to make sure everything was lining up as it should.

Comment: `then got each array from that table` I hope that meant `fed each property from that one variable`

Comment: Yes: `$procTbl = get-process | select ID, Name, Description, MainWindowTitle` then `$procIndex = [array]::indexof($procTbl.ID, [Int32]$IdArray[$i].CookedValue)` and finally `Description = $procTbl.Description[$procIndex];` Same for `Title`.

Comment: Another possible way to speed things up is to execute the PowerShell file from the command line rather than from within the PowerShell ISE. If it is important to view the output in real time, save it to a log file and then tail it. The ISE is much slower than executing the files directly.

Comment: I am not using PowerShell ISE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to my locale with different counter names, I can't test myself:

```
## Q:\Test\2019\04\14\SO_55678790.ps1
$LogicalProcessors = (Get-WmiObject –class Win32_processor).NumberOfLogicalProcessors;

function myTop([String]$SortCol='CPU', [Int32]$top=30) {
    $NameArray = get-counter '\Process(*)\ID Process' -EA SilentlyContinue |
        Select -Expand CounterSamples | Select-Object InstanceName,CookedValue
    $CpuArray = get-counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' -EA SilentlyContinue |
        Select -Expand CounterSamples | Select-Object CookedValue
    $MemArray = get-counter '\Process(*)\Working Set - Private' -EA SilentlyContinue |
        Select -Expand CounterSamples | Select-Object CookedValue

    $proc = Get-Process

    $TopTable = For ($i=0; $i -lt $NameArray.Length; $i++) {
        $procIndex = [array]::indexof($proc.Id, [Int32]$NameArray[$i].CookedValue)
        if ($NameArray[$i].InstanceName -eq '_total') {continue}
        if ($NameArray[$i].InstanceName -eq 'idle') {
            $CPU = ($CpuArray[$i].CookedValue) / $LogicalProcessors
        } else {
            $CPU = $CpuArray[$i].CookedValue;
        }
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name        = $NameArray[$i].InstanceName
            ID          = $NameArray[$i].CookedValue
            CPU         = $CPU
            Mem         = $MemArray[$i].CookedValue
            Description = $proc[$procIndex].Description
            Title       = $proc[$procIndex].MainWindowTitle
        }
    }
    $TopTable | Sort-Object -Descending $SortCol | Select-Object -First $top Name,ID,
      @{Name='CPU'; Expression = {("{0:N1}%" -f $_.CPU) } },
      @{Name='Mem'; Expression = {("{0:N0} kb" -f ($_.Mem /1kb) )} },
      Description, Title
}

While(1) {
    myTop -SortCol CPU -top 12 | ft -a
    sleep 0
    cls
    # pause
}
```

Comment: The single call to `get-counter '\Process(*)\ID Process'` I'm sure is an improvement.   Also the `+=`  operator is, I believe, a ["Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm"](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/), so that is likely to help as well, also see [this](https://powershell.org/2013/09/powershell-performance-the-operator-and-when-to-avoid-it/).   The sorting will not work on the `'CPU'` or `'Mem'` columns after you format them.  However, it still seems to be sluggish.

Comment: @Clay Sorting is a good point, as local time is past midnight I'll leave it up to you to revert that.

Comment: - Fix the sorting and I will mark this as the answer.  I will make new questions out of the other questions. - Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the column joining alternative here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55698377/5060792 .  This allows for a single call to the `Get-Counter` cmdlet which speeds things up.